# What does "transporte es por carrera" mean?

Tags: traducción

I'm asking a hotel if airport pickup is 24 hours a day as I have a super late flight arriving after midnight, and an early flight departing at 5 in the morning. I asked:

> ¿Transporte es 24 horas por día?

Maybe I asked it wrong but the hotel manager responded with:

> Transporte es por carrera.

I looked up in a dictionary and Google translate, but I couldn't find anything that makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: The manager's reply has no sense. You could say something like "¿Hay disponibilidad de transporte las 24 horas?"  o "¿El transporte está disponible en cualquier momento del día?". By the way, are you asking about how to properly formulate the question? or: how it is that the manager replied that?

Comment: Are you sure that the manager said "Transporte es por carrera" instead of "El transporte es por carretera"?

Comment: The question is not correctly formed, but it is quite understandable, in my opinion. But the answer makes no sense at all. Either you heard it wrong or the manager was quite confused.

Comment: I guess he understood another thing, since [carrera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7gRETug) is the word taxis use to refer to their services: _5. f. Cada uno de los servicios que hace un taxi o un vehículo de alquiler transportando clientes de un punto a otro_.

Comment: A possibility is that he understood: "do I pay for 24 hs of transport service, and then I can use it as I like during that period?", so he answered: "No, you pay for each trip". Another possibility is that he meant the shuttle goes an comes at predefined times, so it's available only when it does a trip (carrera).

Comment: It may help if you tell us which country/city you are talking about. You could've heard _carrera_ or _carretera_ In some places transport from the airport to the city is by car but could also be by helicopter. _Carrera_ has been explained already, and _carretera_ is by road.

Answer (score 2):

As fedorqui already said in a comment, *carrera* is a word used by the taxi drivers to refer to the service provided (the trip). So the manager's reply probably refers to what the service was going to cost you. It is hard to know whether he understood you or not. Maybe he was taking as granted that you were going to take a taxi, and usually there is no problem with taxis no matter the time of the arrival/departure (they know the timetables of the airports, so as long as there are customers, there are also taxis).

Nonetheless, in such a situation what I would say would be something like this:

> Mi avión va a salir/llegar de madrugada, ¿habrá algún problema con el transporte hasta el aeropuerto/hotel?

Then the other person will give you advice on what transport to take.